# C programming error in code

Tags: c, linked-list

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int ID;
    int age;
    struct student *next;
};

struct student *head = 0;
struct student *first = 0;
struct student *temp = 0;

void create_list()
{
    static int counter = 1;
    head = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    printf("Enter the student no. %d ID\n",counter);
    scanf_s("%d", &head->ID);
    printf("Enter the student no. %d age\n", counter);
    scanf_s("%d", &head->age);
    if (first != 0)
    {
        temp->next = head;
        temp = head;
    }
    else
    {
        first = temp = head;
    }

    counter++;
}

void read_list()
{
    temp->next = 0;

    temp = first;
    int counter = 1;
    first = 0;
    while (temp != 0)
    {
        printf("------------------Node number : %d---------------\n", counter);
        printf("The Student id is : %d\n", temp->ID);
        printf("The Student age is : %d\n", temp->age);
        counter++;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    printf("NULL\n");
    printf("-------------No. of nodes in the list = %d\n------------------", counter);
}

void delete_list(struct student **head, int position)
{

    if (*head == NULL)
        return;

    struct student* temp = *head;

    if (position == 0)
    {
        *head = temp->next;   
        temp = 0;               
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; temp != NULL && i<position - 1; i++)
        temp = temp->next;

    if (temp == NULL || temp->next == NULL)
        return;

    struct student *next = temp->next->next;

    temp->next=0;  
    temp->next = next;  
}

void main()
{

    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 99)
    {
        printf("Please enter a choice from the list:\n");
        printf("1- Create Node\n");
        printf("2- Read List\n");
        printf("3- Delete Node\n");
        printf("99- Exit\n");
        scanf_s("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            create_list();
            break;
        case 2:
            read_list();
            break;
        case 3:
            delete_list(&head,2);
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

I've been encountering a lot of problems with my delete function. I am creating a linked node list. I created the read and create function but whenever I try to delete a node and shift back all the nodes it gives me back an error. Can I get some help about what is wrong?

The error is that whenever I come again and print the list, it stops and doesn't print anything.

Comment: What's the error? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `<stdlib.h>` declares `malloc()` et al, so there's no need for the non-standard `<malloc.h>` unless you're using some of its extra functionality, which you aren't.  You've not outlined what values you input — or the error output you get.  That's an important part of an MCVE ([MCVE]).  We should not have to guess.  When debugging, you could usefully call your `read_list()` function after each operation.

Comment: Your global variable `temp` is worrying; I'm not clear how it is meant to be used. It seems to be important to you since you carefully set it in the delete code, but why? Similarly, the global variable `next` probably shouldn't be global.  Using the global variable `head` is permissible — it's often not the best choice, but it is OK.  It means you can only manage one list at a time with this code, but that's OK when you're starting out.  Using `void main()` is not valid on Unix-like systems; the correct return type is `int`.  Windows documents `void main()` so it isn't automatically wrong.

Comment: Why are you using `delete_list(&head,2);` with a fixed 2? What is the expected behavior of `delete_list`? it's only to delete the last node?

Comment: @F.Igor i am setting it as an example so if i entered 5 nodes as an example and deleted the 2nd it would shift them back 1 step , and would print 4 nodes again without the 2nd

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I am using the temporary variable globally just to make sure it can be seen between the functions and the main, other than that i make sure i reclear it again by setting it back to zero

Comment: Suggestion: don't!  Also, in your delete code, you have consecutive assignments `temp->next=0; temp->next = next;` — you don't need the first given the second, and I'm not convinced that either is a good idea.  I note that no memory is freed; you're leaking when you delete (assuming you get the delete working to the extent that the node is detached from the list).

Comment: Regarding your delete, positional delete in a single-linked list should look [something like this](https://pastebin.com/k9udK7gQ)

Comment: What are you doing here: `temp->next = head; temp = head;` in `create_list()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If any more questions don't doubt to contact me. Good luck.**

**About createlist()**

*Head should point to the first element of the list, but you are using head to instantiate the newest element added to the list. First and head conceptually are the same. I think you think head should be the last element of the list but it should't. Read more about linked lists. Also you are pointing to head from temp? But wait, what is temp? Can you tell me what is temp at that point in your program? You should't rely on temp, that's why it is called temp. It should be a temporal variable. Not a global variable.*

**About read_list()**

*Why temp-> next = 0? You could be breaking your chain here because we don't know what temp is. Let's continue. So you point to the first element in the list (which should be the same as head). OH MY GOD! You point first to null. Of course you can't read the list twice nor thrice. Once you point first to null you lose your only reference to the first element of the list. It doesn't matter what you do with your other functions. You won't be able to call this function twice in a row and your code will break.*

*I mean. First time you pass you do temp = first. Then first = NULL*

*Second time. temp = first. Buut... first = null? Rings a bell? You won't be able to print anything else.*

*The while loop is ok.*

**About delete_list()**

*Ok you lost me here. You are using head now. But i can tell you, head is absolutely not pointing to the first element in the list. If anything it is the last element on the list and (head->next = random stuff) and if lucky (head->next = null). I am not sure, but if head would point to the first element on the list (but it is not) this function may be ok or close to ok. But don't take my word on this one, i am really tired right now.*

**Summary:**

*Your functions are wrong. There is not one function breaking your code but many. Your main problem is that you are messing up things with the pointers. If i were you i would:*

- Remove first and temp as global variables.
- Review linked lists [Linked Lists](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~adamchik/15-121/lectures/Linked%20Lists/linked%20lists.html)
- Use temp as a local variable in your functions.
- Freed allocated memory and if possible check for errors when allocating.
- Head should always point to the first element in the list. You should't update head, unless you add the first element to the list or remove the last one.
- The only case where you should update head is when adding an element to the beginning of the list but i encourage you to try making the program without this feature first.

If you allocate memory (for ex, calloc or malloc) you should always freed that memory and point the pointers to NULL (It is good practice). The way you programmed you are leaking memory.

Also you should't have temp as a global variable. It can produce problems you wouldn't have if you weren't using it. Also having three global variables makes things harder to review or debug. When the only global variable you should have is head.

**I wrote an alternative for your code if you want to check it.**

**Explanation of the code:**

*I don't check for user input but it can be easily added in the main function. 
There are 5 functions: addLastElement, addFirstElement, deleteList, deleteElement and readList.*

- readList: Prints the list.
- addLastElement: IF there is no element it will add the head. If there
  are elements, it will add a new element at the end of the list. It
  doesn't update the head unless head is null.
- addFirstElement: Adds an element at the beginning of the list. This
  function always updates the head.
- deleteElement: Deletes element in the position passed as an argument.
  And it frees the memory.
- deleteList: Will delete all elements from the list and free the
  memory.

All the functions except for readList will update the variable "size" of the struct list accordingly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int id;
    int age;
    struct student *next;
};

struct list
{
    struct student *head;
    int size;
};

void addFirstElement(struct list *list, int id, int age)
{
    struct student *temp;
    temp = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if (temp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Couldn't allocate memory\n");
    }
    temp -> id = id;
    temp -> age = age;
    temp->next = list -> head;
    list->head = temp;
    list->size++;
}

void addLastElement(struct list *list, int id, int age)
{
    struct student *new;
    struct student *temp;
    new = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if (new == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: Couldn't allocate memory\n");
    }
    new->id = id;
    new->age = age;
    new->next = NULL;
    if (list->head == NULL)
    {
        list->head = new;
    }
    else
    {
        temp = list -> head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next = new;
    }
    list->size++;
}

void readList(struct list *list)
{
    struct student *temp = list->head;

    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("ID: %d - Age: %d\n", temp->id, temp->age);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

void deleteList(struct list *list)
{
    struct student *temp;
    struct student *previous;

    temp = list->head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        free(previous);
    }
    previous = NULL;
    list->size = 0;
    list->head = NULL;
}

void deleteElement(struct list *list, int position)
{
    if (list->head == NULL)
        return;

    if (position < 0 || position > ((list->size) - 1))
    {
        printf("The list is not that big\n");
        return;
    }

    struct student *temp = list->head;
    struct student *previous = NULL;
    int i = 0;

    temp = list->head;
    while (i != position)
    {
        previous = temp;
        temp = temp->next;
        i++;
    }

    if (previous == NULL)
    {
        list->head = list->head->next;
    }
    else
    {
        previous->next = temp->next;
    }
    list->size--;
    free(temp);
    temp = NULL;
    return;
}
int main()
{
    struct list list;
    int i;
    list.size = 0;
    list.head = NULL;

    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        addLastElement(&list, i, (i+1)*10);
    }

    deleteElement(&list, 5);

    addFirstElement(&list, 100, 50);

    readList(&list);

    deleteList(&list);

    return 1;
}
```

Output:

```
ID: 100 - Age: 50
ID: 0 - Age: 10
ID: 1 - Age: 20
ID: 2 - Age: 30
ID: 3 - Age: 40
ID: 4 - Age: 50
ID: 6 - Age: 70
ID: 7 - Age: 80
ID: 8 - Age: 90
ID: 9 - Age: 100
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code in `create_list()` does not check that the memory allocation succeeded.  It also doesn't set the `next` element reliably.  This means that if you add 5 nodes and print them, you get to see only the most recently added node in the list.  Because the list is not constructed correctly, your delete code doesn't stand much chance of working (it crashes for me, and I'm too lazy to work out exactly why; it's probably because of dereferencing a null pointer).  One key problem is confusion over the role of `head` and `first` — `first` does point to the first element of the list, but is never updated, and `head` doesn't point to the first element in the list, contrary to normal conventions.  As already noted in comments, `temp` is mostly confusing — it should not exist as a global variable.  It is a major factor in your problems.

Here's an alternative implementation.  It doesn't prompt for input; it is hardwired to add 5 students and then delete them all.  It uses `head` as a single global variable pointing to the first structure in the list.  It adds new elements at the start of the list.  It prints the list after each student is added or deleted, which allows for complete checking.  When printing, it uses one line for each student.  It frees the memory when a student is deleted.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct student
{
    int ID;
    int age;
    struct student *next;
};

struct student *head = 0;

static void create_list(int ID, int age)
{
    struct student *node = (struct student *)malloc(sizeof(struct student));
    if (node == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes\n", sizeof(*node));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    node->ID = ID;
    node->age = age;
    node->next = 0;
    if (head != 0)
        node->next = head;
    head = node;
}

static void print_list(void)
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (struct student *node = head; node != 0; node = node->next)
    {
        printf("-- Node %2d: ID = %.5d, age = %d\n", ++counter, node->ID, node->age);
    }
    printf("-- No. of nodes in the list = %d\n\n", counter);
}

static void delete_list(int position)
{
    int counter = 0;
    struct student *node = head;
    struct student *prev = 0;
    while (node != 0 && ++counter != position)
    {
        prev = node;
        node = node->next;
    }

    if (node == NULL)
        return;
    if (prev == NULL)
    {
        assert(node == head);
        struct student *old = head;
        head = head->next;
        free(old);
    }
    else
    {
        assert(node != head);
        prev->next = node->next;
        free(node);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    create_list(10102, 19);
    print_list();
    create_list(23147, 20);
    print_list();
    create_list(30001, 21);
    print_list();
    create_list(47721, 18);
    print_list();
    create_list(59286, 20);
    print_list();
    delete_list(2);
    print_list();
    delete_list(3);
    print_list();
    delete_list(2);
    print_list();
    delete_list(1);
    print_list();
    delete_list(1);
    print_list();
    return 0;
}
```

Example output:

```
-- Node  1: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 1

-- Node  1: ID = 23147, age = 20
-- Node  2: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 2

-- Node  1: ID = 30001, age = 21
-- Node  2: ID = 23147, age = 20
-- Node  3: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 3

-- Node  1: ID = 47721, age = 18
-- Node  2: ID = 30001, age = 21
-- Node  3: ID = 23147, age = 20
-- Node  4: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 4

-- Node  1: ID = 59286, age = 20
-- Node  2: ID = 47721, age = 18
-- Node  3: ID = 30001, age = 21
-- Node  4: ID = 23147, age = 20
-- Node  5: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 5

-- Node  1: ID = 59286, age = 20
-- Node  2: ID = 30001, age = 21
-- Node  3: ID = 23147, age = 20
-- Node  4: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 4

-- Node  1: ID = 59286, age = 20
-- Node  2: ID = 30001, age = 21
-- Node  3: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 3

-- Node  1: ID = 59286, age = 20
-- Node  2: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 2

-- Node  1: ID = 10102, age = 19
-- No. of nodes in the list = 1

-- No. of nodes in the list = 0
```